# Delete items from a dictionary using another list with IDs of unwanted items in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a dictionary and a list. A dictionary with IDs and values and a list with IDs of items that I want to delete from the dictionary. What function sould I use? Is it even possible?

The dictionary contains the IDs of points and their coordinates. I want to delete those points which IDs is stored in the list.

Comment: You probably want the first list to be a dict.

Comment: @Samwise yes, that's right!

Comment: Please provide actual example data with your expected outputs. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added, thank you. No, I am new to Python.

Comment: Please include a sample input and output

Answer (score 2):

This demonstrates how you might do this with two lists, as in the first version of your question:

```
>>> a = [(1, "foo"), (2, "bar"), (3, "ola"), (4, "qux")]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> [pair for pair in a if pair[0] not in b]
[(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')]
```

Here we convert `a` to a dict:

```
>>> d = dict(a)
>>> d
{1: 'foo', 2: 'bar', 3: 'ola', 4: 'qux'}
```

and then iterate over `b` to delete all those keys from `d`:

```
>>> for i in b:
...     del(d[i])
...
>>> d
{1: 'foo', 2: 'bar'}
>>>
```

The second version (with a dict) is significantly more efficient because it only requires one iteration over `b`; the first version with the two lists does one iteration over `b` for each element in `a`.  In general, a dict is the better way to store associated pairs of data if you want to use one to look up the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. This takes a list of unwanted items and loops through it, deleting the items in the dictionary one by one.

```py
dictionary = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}

#List of unwanted items
unwantedItems = {"brand", "year"}

#Looping through all the unwanted items and removing them from the list
for i in unwantedItems:
    if i in dictionary:
        del dictionary[i]

print(dictionary)
```

Edit: Sorry for not making this a function unlike other answers

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
def function(dictionary, del_list):
    for e in del_list:
        if e in dictionary:
            del dictionary[e]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to avoid `KeyErrors` and delete all (even non-existing) IDs is to use [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop):

```py
d = dict(zip(range(10), 'abcdefghij'))
l = [1, 4, 6, 6, 3, 11]

print(d) # {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j'}

for elem in l:
    # would raise KeyErrors if key is not in d
    # del d[elem]

    # return None if key doesn't exist
    d.pop(elem, None)

print(d) # {0: 'a', 2: 'c', 5: 'f', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j'}
```